# Bash - Copy files from directory

Tags: bash, copy

I have a folder which contains some folders:

```
main
  \_ Dir 1
  \_ Dir 2
  \_ ...
  \_ Dir 40
```

I need to open each sub-folder, copy all the files and paste them in another folder, the same folder for all this sub-folder.

How can I do that in a smart way?

The only thing that comes to my mind was create a list with the name of all folders and then use a simple script to open, copy and paste but I'm sure that there is a faster way than write all the names.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try:

```
cp main/*/* /path/to/otherfolder/
```

If you want to be warned before overwriting a file, use the `-i` option:

```
cp -i main/*/* /path/to/otherfolder/
```

Comment: Hypothetical question- what if you didn't know how many subdirectories might be in `main/*/*`? Is there a way to run this command where the `/*/*` might act recursively and effectively be `/*/*/*/*...`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement correct, you can try this `find` command:

```
cd main

find . -mindepth 1 -type f -exec cp '{}' /dest/dir +
```

Assuming your filenames are not duplicate across the sub folders in `main` directory.

Comment: find: missing argument of `-exec'

Comment: Try: `find . -mindepth 1 -type f -exec cp '{}' /dest/dir \;`